# How to extract selected value from DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need help to extract what i select here :

```
<% var equipo = Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.campeonato.equipo, 
                 new SelectList(Model.campeonato.equipo, "idEquipo", "nombre", Model.campeonato.equipo.First().idEquipo), 
                 new { @required = "required", @class = "infofield" });%>

<%:Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idJugadora, 
                  new SelectList(Model.campeonato.equipo.Where(d=>d.idEquipo.Equals(equipo)).ToList(), "idJugadora", "nombre", Model.campeonato.equipo.First().jugadora), 
                  new { @required = "required", @class = "infofield" })%>
```

If i do it on that way, it doesn't appear the dropdownlist in the View :S

Answer (score 1):

your can access the value via the Model you post.

```
public ActionResult Edit(campeonato campeonato_model)
{
   //Console.Write(equipo_model.equipo);
}
```

Comment: What i need is to make a dropdownlist selection updates another dropdownlist

Comment: I suggest do it by Ajax (jQuery etc) to populer idJugadora dropdownlist, if you prefer server-side, you can make a onchange() event for equipo dropdown and POST request to another ActionResult, for exmaple : public ActionResult Selected_equipo(string idEquipo) { ... return View(); }

Comment: ok, but u can explain how to extract the selected value on the dropdown list, i think var equipo = html.dropdownlistfor(....) is not the correct way